# How to get the returned reference to a vector?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

I found two ways to get the reference returned by the function.

```
vector<int> vec1 = {4,5,6};

vector<int>& rtn_vec(void)
{
    return vec1;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> &vec2 = rtn_vec(); //way 1
    vector<int> vec3 = rtn_vec(); //way2

    vec2[0] = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

I understand way 1 means passing the reference to `vec1` to `&vec2`, so `vec2[0] = 3;` changes `vec1` to `{3,5,6}`.

But about way 2, I have 2 questions:

1. Why can I pass a reference (`vector<int>&`) to an instance (`vector<int>`), how does it work?
2. Does way 2 involve deep copy? Because I run this code and `vector<int> vec3 = rtn_vec();` seems just copy `vec1` to `vec3`.

Comment: Since the function returns a reference to `vec1`, way 1 is equivalent to `vector<int>& vec2 = vec1;`, way 2 is equivalent to `vector<int> vec3 = vec1;`.

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<int> vec3 = rtn_vec(); //way2
```

This allocates a new vector and invokes a copy constructor, so yes, this is "deep" copy.

Actually, this is in no way different from simply writing

```
vector<int> &vec2 = vec1;
vector<int> vec3 = vec1;
```

Or to make things even clearer

```
vector<int> &return_value = vec1;
vector<int> &vec2 = return_value;
vector<int> vec3 = return_value;
```

(Though be careful with term "deep". If it was `vector<int*>`, then only the pointers would be copied, not the `int`s themselves.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but I still don't know why can I do `vector<int> &return_value = vec1; vector<int> vec3 = return_value;` Because `return_value` is a reference, but `vec3` is not a reference. I thought reference is similar to pointer, but I can't do `int a; int *p = &a; int b = p;` this cause build error, so why can I do this while using reference ?

Comment: @Wei-ShouYang, in your example instead of `int b = p;` you should do `int b = *p`. References are somewhat like pointers (and technically _are_ pointers), just you don't need to use `&` for address and `*` for accessing the value.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy-construct `vec3`, a *shallow* copy is made (C++ doesn't really do "deep" copy).  All the elements in the vector are copied *by value*, just as with any other copy of a `std::vector`.

Comment: I don't see how you could copy `vec` and more "deeply" than what happens with `vector<int> vec3 = rtn_vec();`. It's not a vector of pointers.

Comment: No, but if it was a vector of pointers, then the pointed-to values wouldn't be copied.  Hence, it's a shallow copy.